# Email signature image alignment

Tags: html, email, outlook, email-signature

I have this html email signature code, when I send my email signature from Gmail to another platform, it works fine. However, when I send it from Outlook to another platform, the alignment of the embedded image in the middle gets distorted.

```html
<body style="
      font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
      font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
      font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    ">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <table style="border-spacing: 0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="background-color: #8fc7c1;">

                                <table style="line-height: 12px;border-spacing: 0;padding: 0px 28px 5px 40px"
                                    cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td
                                                style="font-weight: bold;line-height: 120%;font-size: 20px;color: #ffffff">
                                                abbababa
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table style="line-height: 12px; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0px 28px 5px 40px; "
                                    cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="font-size: 11px; color: #5a5e6b; letter-spacing: 1.3px">
                                                Pineapples
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table style="border-spacing: 0; padding: 10px 107px 0px 40px;" cellpadding="0"
                                    cellspacing="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x55/000/fff&text=aaaa" alt="Cyber Essentials">
                                           </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            <div>
                                <td>
                                    <table style="border-spacing: 0;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <img style=""
                                                    src="https://dummyimage.com/150/170/cf1fcf/0011ff&text=enqiwehi2ehiu32r"
                                                    alt="" width="168px" />

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </div>
                            <td style="background-color: #f6f6f6; padding-left: 24px;">
                                <table style="line-height: 13.8px; padding-bottom: 5px;border-spacing: 0;"
                                    cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding-right: 7.5px">
                                                <img src=""
                                                    alt="" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="font-weight: 400; font-size: 11px; color: #5a5e6b">
                                                <a href="#"
                                                    style="text-decoration: none; color: #4d4c5e">1228 343 222</a>
                                                <!-- |
                          <a
                            href="tel:+4407539938874"
                            style="text-decoration: none; color: #4d4c5e"
                            >07539 938 874</a
                          > -->
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table style="line-height: 13.8px; padding-bottom: 5px; border-spacing: 0;"
                                    cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding-right: 7.5px">
                                                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                                    <img src=""
                                                        alt="" /></a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="font-weight: 400; font-size: 11px; color: #5a5e6b">
                                                <a href="#"
                                                    style="text-decoration: none; color: #4d4c5e"
                                                    target="_blank">SAWF.com</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table style="line-height: 13.8px;padding-bottom: 5px; border-spacing: 0"
                                    cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding-right: 7.5px">
                                                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                                    <img src=""
                                                        alt="" /></a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="font-weight: 400; font-size: 11px; color: #5a5e6b">
                                                <a href="#"
                                                    style="text-decoration: none; color: #4d4c5e"
                                                    target="_blank">abc@abc.co.uk</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table style="line-height: 13.8px;padding-bottom: 5px;border-spacing: 0;width: 270px"
                                    cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding-right: 7.5px">
                                                <img src=""
                                                    alt="" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td
                                                style="font-weight: 400;font-size: 11px;color: #5a5e6b;padding-right: 24px">
                                                H 41 st3
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table style="line-height: 12px;border-spacing: 0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <td style="line-height: 14.4px;font-size: 12px;font-weight: 500;color: #5A5E6B">
                                        Schedule a meeting:
                                    </td>
                                </table>
                                <table style="line-height: 13.8px;padding-bottom: 5px;border-spacing: 0" cellpadding="0"
                                    cellspacing="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding-right: 7.5px;">
                                                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                                    <img src=""
                                                        alt="" />
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="font-weight: 400;font-size: 11px;color: #5a5e6b !important">
                                                <a href="#"
                                                    style="text-decoration: none; color: #5a5e6b"
                                                    target="_blank">abbababab</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

my images are not aligned properly when I send email sigmature from outlook to any other platform.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71fJh.png)

I want my image alignment properly when I share my email signature from outlook to any other platform.